# Can't use some variables under environment tags in YAML azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Under the "tags" block, I need something that is very unique for the given build run, such as $(Build.BuildId), $(Build.BuildNumber), the current DateTime, or some random number. We cannot use variables like $(Build.BuildId) or $(Build.BuildNumber) because their values aren't set at the time expressions are evaluated. This means that the values under the "tags" block need to be resolved during compile time, i.e., when you get the full YAML.

How can I get a unique value their under tags?

```
stages:
- stage: Block_VMs
  displayName: Tag VMs for installation
  jobs:
  - job: tag VMs
    pool: 
      name: TFS-Self-Hosted-Pool
    variables: 
    - name: RequiredMachines
      value: 55
    steps:
    - script: Runs a cmd line custom tool that makes API calls and adds Tag $(Build.BuildNumber) to 55 machines or VMs from the environment. The value for $(Build.BuildNumber) works fine here
    
- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: Block_VMs
  displayName: 'Test Deploy'
  jobs:
  - deployment: Test_job
    environment:
      name: myEnvironment
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: $(Build.BuildNumber) # so I can run this job on the same 55 machines tagged above, but the value for $(Build.BuildNumber) doesn't work here.
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
            steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: Deploy-Steps...
```

All I am trying to do is add tags to some machines in the environment and then run a second job on those machines that I tagged in the first job. Since my case involves parallel runs in the same pipeline, I need Build.BuildNumber or some unique tag that is unique for every build run.

Answer (score 0):

May I assume some of the VM resources in `myEnvironment` are tagged with such unique variable values as `$(Build.BuildId)` and`$(Build.BuildNumber)`? Does a pipeline build automatically populate tags for certain VM resources under this environment? Because if not, It is fairly confusing why you would tag the VM resources with `$(Build.BuildId)` and `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops#add-and-manage-tags), Kindly note that,

> Tags give you a way to target a set of specific VMs in an environment for deployment.

Thus, you can select a set of VMs from this environment with expected tags to roll out your deployment.

Besides, according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), the varaibles `$(Build.BuildId)` and `$(Build.BuildNumber)` are **not** available in template (complie time). Their values will be expanded as `$(Build.BuildId)` and `$(Build.BuildNumber)`during compile time rather than their actual contents. And the pipeline deployment plan is required to be set at compile time, therefore we cannot use such build varaibles to determine which VM rerouces are used for deployment.

[image]

If your requirement is to set the tags for VM before deployment, you may consider using [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script), which are accessible during compile time. The deployment will only be rolled out on the VM resources with required tag.

```
parameters:
- name: vmTag
  default: tag1
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Test Deploy'
  jobs:
  - deployment: Test_job
    environment:
      name: myEnvironment
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: ${{ parameters.vmTag }} # need some unique variable here
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
            steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: 'Write-Host Deploy-Steps...'
```

[image]

See more details in the documents below.

[Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

[Expressions - Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Hope the information helps.

Comment: We have a large environment with thousands of machines. For each YAML build run, the first job runs a custom script and randomly selects around 50 machines from the environment and tags them with the corresponding Build.BuildNumber, and the second deployment job needs to be run on the same environment machines tagged in first job. That's why we need Build.BuildNumber or any random value as tag

Comment: Can you specify your requirement in the  original post? Please also add the first job to tag VM resources in this environment. It is helpful for us to understand how you managed to tag your VM resources and your workflow.

Comment: Just updated the post. Thanks for helping :)